# I'm having an issue when I create an AR APK

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, ar-foundation

I'm having an issue when I create an AR APK. I had already finished the application in Unity; I was just fixing the design. But when I install it on the phone, the AR doesn't work, and this still happens even if I create a project from scratch. The same thing happened when I created it with Xamarin, so I don't know if it's something with the computer or what, but even the versions that used to work are not worth anything anymore.

**I have already created the application from scratch, just with an object in different versions of Unity. I changed the code, I did it without code, and I even installed new versions. i have used other phones**